# Protecting PC parallel port interface when controlling external devices

Tags: parallel-port

I need to control two devices with the PC's parallel port simultaneously.  To protect the port and provide some sort of a buffering, I thought to use an optocouplers and two ULN2003 Darlington arrays.  I wonder whether this design is reasonable.  Maybe one ULN2003 could be enough in this situation?  Alternatively, is there a simple solution for the parallel port interface?

[image: schematic]

Comment: Are you controlling an inductive load? What are R3 and R4 for? Could you use two channels of one ULN2003?

Comment: Note that some parallel ports may not have enough output drive to light an opto directly. Test your design on several different parallel ports, or add a SN7416/17 to drive the optos. This may mean adding a 5v isolated supply...

Comment: Texas Instruments has a great series of videos on the subject of [galvanic isolation](https://training.ti.com/ti-precision-labs-isolation-what-galvanic-isolation) which discusses inductive, capacitive and optical isolation techniques. The capacitive isolation types use very little current.

Comment: In principle you may get something like this to work (back in the day many a project began with debug LEDs stuck directly in the DB25...).  But in practice, start by realizing that actual bit-manipulatable parallel ports are nearly extinct.  You probably want to use an USB-enabled MCU, and move enough of the control task to the MCU firmware to handle reliability/timing concerns.

Comment: @tim, the load is not inductive.  R3 and R4 are load resistors.  I need to use all 4 channels of ULN2003; only one channel is shown on the circuit.

Comment: @Chris Stratton, this particular parallel port can drive the optocouplers directly.

Comment: @AntonSheinin, from the [ULN2003 datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/uln2001.pdf), it has 7 channels with flyback diodes for inductive loads. Are you trying to control 8 resistive loads as 4 pairs? On page 6 of the datasheet it states that Vce(sat) is 0.9 to 1.6 V. Considering that the supply is 5 V, is this acceptable? Consider using 4 galvanic isolators to drive 4 NMOS FETs as low-side switches; one for each pair.

Comment: @AntonSheinin, what frequency will the switches be operating at? Is it time critical, or just an infrequent on/off switch? As ChrisStratton said, there will be timing issues with a general purpose multi-tasking PC.

Comment: @tim, that's a good point, te ULN2003 is mostly suited for driving inductive loads.  I will try to use the galvanic isolators and FETs, as you suggested.  As for the time, it is not critical - the comand from the port will be sent once in several minutes.